# execute bash variable (contains another variables) as a command and assign the result to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, substitution

I see that similar questions were answered before but my scenario is a little bit different:

- I need to store a command in a variable in order to I can log it before running
- the command contains variables that can contain space between the words
- the result of the execution must assign to a new variable

**This is the command that works properly from the terminal:**

```
java -jar ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sql-command-line-tool/sql-runner-0.2.2-with-dependencies.jar -v -U ${DB_USERNAME} -P ${DB_PASSWORD} -j jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME} "select 1 from dual"
```

**Variables:**

- DB_HOST=oracle-db
- DB_PORT=1521
- DB_NAME=ORCLPDB1.localdomain
- DB_USERNAME="SYS as SYSDBA"
- DB_PASSWORD=Oradoc_db1

**Test:**

```
$ echo $DB_USERNAME
"SYS as SYSDBA"
```

This is how I want to use but this does not work:

```
echo "checking whether database server is up and running..."
_COMMAND="java -jar ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sql-command-line-tool/sql-runner-0.2.2-with-dependencies.jar -v -U ${DB_USERNAME} -P ${DB_PASSWORD} -j jdbc:oracle:thin:@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME} \"select 1 from dual\""
echo "command: $_COMMAND"
_RESULT=$($_COMMAND)
_SHOW_MESSAGE=true

while [[ ${_RESULT} ]]
do
    if [ $_SHOW_MESSAGE = "true" ]; then echo "the database server is not running yet, waiting..."; fi
    if [ $VERBOSE = "false" ]; then _SHOW_MESSAGE="false"; fi
    sleep 0.5
    _JSON=$($_COMMAND)
done
echo "database server is up and running"
```

Error:

```
Unmatched arguments from index 4: 'SYSDBA"', '"select', '1', 'from', 'dual"'
```

The jar I use is available from [here](https://github.com/zappee/sql-runner/tree/master/bin).

I have tried to use single and double quotes in different ways, tried to use `eval` but non of them worked properly.

What I missed?

Comment: While executing the `_COMMAND`, you'll need to wrap the command output in quotes: `_RESULT="$($_COMMAND)"` if those can have newlines etc

Comment: Also, try pasting the script on [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check for default bash errors: `_RESULT=$($_COMMAND)
          ^-- SC2090: Quotes/backslashes in this variable will not be respected.`

Comment: @0stone0 unfortunately extra quotas around `_COMMAND` did not help.

Comment: It's not just the quotes around `_COMMAND`, but also on those other assignments where the might be quotes/newlines in the response.

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: The link given by glenn above explains _why_ the `$_COMMAND` approach generally is unworkable; it's very much worth reading. Using a function or array instead of a string to store commands is very much the Right Thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some general issues I'll try to address.

---

1. There's no [Bash Shebang](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-shebang/)
2. While creating the command, your username contains a space (`DB_USERNAME="SYS as SYSDBA"`) therefore you'll need to wrap those in quotes;

   ```
   COMMAND="... -v -U '${DB_USERNAME}' -P ${DB_PASSWORD} ...
   ```
3. [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable);

   ```
   while [[ "${_RESULT}" ]]
   ```

   ```
   _RESULT="$($_COMMAND)"
   ```

   ```
   _JSON="$($_COMMAND)"
   ```

   ```
   if [ "$VERBOSE" = "false" ]
   ```

---

Using a took like https://www.shellcheck.net/ will help finding those bash errors

Answer (score -1):

In general it is not a good practice to define a bash command as a variable. I would recommend:

1. Create an alias
2. Create a bash [function](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-functions.php)
3. Create a bash [script](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0120.php) and call it with either `source` or `bash` appropriately.

## Bash function example

```sh
_COMMAND() {
    # Argument parsing with default values/error statements
    if [ -z ${ORACLE_HOME+x} ]
    then 
        echo "ERROR: ORACLE_HOME not defined"
        return 0
    fi
    DB_HOST=${1:-"oracle-db"}
    DB_PORT=${2:-1521}
    DB_NAME=${3:-"ORCLPDB1.localdomain"}
    DB_USERNAME=${4:-"SYS as SYSDBA"}
    DB_PASSWORD=${5:-"Oradoc_db1"}
    # Execute command
    java -jar "${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sql-command-line-tool/sql-runner-0.2.2-with-dependencies.jar" -v -U "${DB_USERNAME}" -P "${DB_PASSWORD}" -j jdbc:oracle:thin:@"${DB_HOST}":${DB_PORT}/"${DB_NAME}" "select 1 from dual"
}
```

After defining this function you can capture the result of the call with:

```sh
_RESULT="$(_COMMAND)"
```

Comment: Please don't answer duplicative questions. See the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Such questions should be closed as duplicates; and then, if the canonical instances aren't sufficiently well-answered, new answers can/should be added directly on them.